# Raphael Javascript text not displaying correctly

Tags: raphael

I have some text being displayed and I am using the Raphael JS library.  I want the 'firstname' text to be size 25px, but it is not working.  I am passing in a JS variable to the Raphael part and maybe that is part of the problem.  If anyone could help me I would appreciate it.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="raphael.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">   

var string = "J\no\ne"; 

</script>
</head> 

<body>  

Text: <input type="text" id="words" value="" /> 
<input type="button" value="Animate" onclick="animate()" /> 
<div id='msg'></div> 
<div id='num'></div>
<div id='letters'></div>
<!--<div id="letters2"></div>-->
<div id="draw-here-raphael" style="height: 200px; width: 400px; margin-top:0px;"> 
</div> 
<div id="elps" style="margin-left:100px;"/>  

<script type="text/javascript"> //all your javascript goes here  
var r = new Raphael("draw-here-raphael"); 
var firstname = r.text(95,100, string).attr({font: "25px"}); 
var name = r.text(100,100, string);
name.blur(1);
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try var firstname = r.text(95,100, string).attr({"font-size": 25});

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the raphael js file after the jQuery file.

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="raphael.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try var firstname = r.text(95,100, string).attr({"font-size": 25});

Comment: Cool, I'll post this as a seperate answer and you can accept it.