# Raphael JS ignores text style like .attr({'font-size': 12})

Tags: raphael

I'm trying to write text with Raphael JS, but it completely ignores the text style attributes. Other attributes like fill, fill-opacity, cursor etc. will work, but font-size, font-family etc. won't. Here's my code:

```
paper.text(40, 80, 'teste').attr({fill: '#fff', 'font-size': 120});
```

Note that the 'fill' attribute works perfectly, but the 'font-size' doesn't. I've searched the forum and found a lot of questions answered about text problems ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613079/raphael-javascript-text-not-displaying-correctly)), but no one seems to be having this specific kind of problem.

Any idea of what could I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me your example works: http://jsfiddle.net/CdTDZ/ (latest Chrome)

Comment: Thanks, you haven't solved my problem, but testing it on Fiddle showed me the way. +1 for that. I'll post an answer with the solution, so other people having the same problem can easily fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to solve it. There was a CSS rule overriding every text style:

```
* {font: 12px Arial;}
```

I haven't write the CSS, plus this is my first experience with Raphael JS, so I was twice unaware of it. Hope my case can help someone in the future. Thanks.